# Compile error in Qt/C++

Tags: qt, gcc, g++, openbr

I am trying to compile an example from a library.
I have Qt installed but I think I have to link it and I don't know how.

This is the error:

```
g++ face_recognition.cpp -o test

In file included from face_recognition.cpp:29:0:
/usr/local/include/openbr/openbr_plugin.h:22:23: fatal error: QDataStream: No such file or directory
 #include <QDataStream>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile a Qt application directly with **g++** because the application must first go through Qt's [moc compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html).

If you want to build a Qt application from the cmd-line, make sure you define an appropriate **.pro** file that specifies the Qt modules and other 3rd party headers/libraries you want might to use. For instance:

```
QT += core widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Then [invoke `qmake`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) on the command line in the same directory as the **.pro** file to build the appropriate Makefiles, and finally execute `make` to build the app.